# Should ViewModel inherit DependencyObject in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, dependency-properties

I tried to create a simple `UserControl` in WPF using MVVM. Now I need to create a dependency property for the `UserControl`, so I tried to create the dependency property in `UserControlViewModel` (I don't want to be in code-behind).

In order to create a dependency property in `UserControlViewModel` I need to inherit from `DependencyObject`. Is it a good practice to inherit `DependencyObject` in `UserControlViewModel`? That is, is it a good way to follow MVVM for designing a `UserControl`?

Comment: It is not a good practice to inherite DependencyObject in ViewModel when using the pattern MVVM. Instead use INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 9):

If you have created a custom control with properties that you want them to be **bindable** (e.g. the following code), you **cannot** use `INotifyPropertyChanged` and you **must** use a `DependencyObject`.

```
<MyUserControl MyDependencyProperty="{Binding PropertyPath}"  />
```

But when using `DependencyObjects` you should keep in mind that:

1. `DependencyObjects` are not marked as serializable.
2. The `DependencyObject` class overrides and seals both the `Equals()` and
       `GetHashCode()` methods.
3. A `DependencyObject` has thread affinity - it
       can only be accessed on the thread on which it was created.

   - To see a good MVVM example that discusses implementation of INPC and DP in View-Model see this [article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13536.easy-mvvm-examples-in-extreme-detail.aspx).
   - For more on the INPC vs DP debate, read [this blog](http://kentb.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/view-models-pocos-versus.html).