# My ViewModel should inherit from DependencyObject?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

Okay so basically my goal is to set up a Binding in code instead of with XAML.
The source property is a custom dependency property that is a string. The target property is located in the ViewModel, and it is also a string, but it is not a dependency property (since the ViewModel isn't a DependencyObject, of course).

So the target property is simply a string property (we will call this property MyTextProperty).

This binding approach works via XAML (only tried it with x:bind so far), but I can't seem to be able to pull this off with pure C#.

BindingOperations.SetBinding() expects the target to be a dependency property, but MyTextProperty is just a simple string property that is located in my ViewModel.

I just want to know if there is a way to make this work. Does my ViewModel need to be a DependencyObject? It SEEMS that it would work if it was, although I never tried it. Would that approach be considered a good pattern/practice? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be to create a binding with a OneWayToSource or a TwoWay binding. In this way it's possible to bind to the DependencyProperty of your control and to the "normal" property in the viewmodel

Answer (score 1):

> My ViewModel should inherit from DependencyObject?
>
> Does my ViewModel need to be a DependencyObject?

No and no. It should not as [Bahman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1648849/bahman-aries) states:

> 1. DependencyObjects are not marked as serializable.
> 2. The DependencyObject class overrides and seals both the Equals() and GetHashCode() methods.
> 3. A DependencyObject has thread affinity - it can only be accessed on the thread on which it was created.

[Tell me more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30422927/585968)

What I tend to do is create a `UserControl` and expose the dependency properties there.  You can override the `OnxxxPropertyChanged` to let your view model know of changes.

With this approach, your control will participate in dependency property communication in the way WPF was designed for.

Considering you are already thinking of using DependencyProperties tells me that you have a foreign body that wants to set control properties and does not have access to the underlying viewmodel.  DPs are perfect for that.

Otherwise, if we were simply talking about the view's code-behind you would just talk directly to the view model and be done with it.

Comment: I was wondering about this. Does it have to be a user control, though? I have little experience with complex DependencyObjects but wouldn't it be simpler to just create a Class and have that class inherit from DependencyObject, rather than create a full-blown UserControl (which I guess includes a pointless .xaml file)? Then put the properties in that class and go from there...

Comment: @JonathanAcinity Generally, if you are using `DependencyObject`s, it means some other control/window is referring to it, otherwise you would just talk to the underlying view model. Creating a `UserControl` is trivial.  By the way, I'm not talking about embedding what-ever you have now into a `UserControl`, rather it should be turned into one.

Comment: Ohh, so you mean my example MyTextProperty should be a UserControl itself, for the sole purpose of setting and getting text from it? O_o

Comment: No, `MyTextProperty` would be a dependency property on the control/window.  Whatever it is that currently has XAML behind it.

Answer (score 1):

> BindingOperations.SetBinding() expects the target to be a dependency property, but MyTextProperty is just a simple string property that is located in my ViewModel.

You are misunderstanding binding target and binding source : the expected *target* dependency property is the property of the visual XAML control (i.e. a `Text` property of a `TextBlock` Control). Your view model property `MyTextProperty` is the *source* of the binding.

So, no, your view model does not need to inherit from `DependencyObject`.

Here a [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863(v=vs.110).aspx) on how to configure a binding by code.

BUT, by doing so, you would have to reference uour visual control in your view model and this is a bad practice.